# Implementing Call Answer Functionality in Mobile Notifications for Twilio Integration in a PWA

Tags: notifications, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a Progressive Web App (PWA) that includes Twilio calling functionality. Upon loading the calling JavaScript, a socket connection is established via a Node server, assigning a unique socket ID to each client. When there's an incoming call through Twilio, a notification is displayed within the PWA interface, presenting options to "Answer" or "Hangup" the call. However, when attempting to answer the call from a real mobile device via the notification prompt, the call abruptly disconnects. This discrepancy in behavior between mobile  testing environments has left me puzzled, as I'm unsure of the underlying issue.But it is working in desktop chrome browser, not in real device PWA.

Anyone please suggest how to fix?

I aim to implement a feature where, upon clicking the "Answer" button within the notification on a mobile device, the incoming call should be successfully answered, and the notification status transitions from "Incoming call" to "In progress."